# Import es module file from CommonJS TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, commonjs

I'm trying to import a package where its `package.json` specifies `"type": "module"`.  I saw [Can Typescript import CommonJS Modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36511233/3120446), but its solution (`--allowJs`) does not work for me.

I've tried setting various values in my `tsconfig.json` for `module`, `moduleResolution`, allow `allowJs`.  Both `esModuleInteropt` and `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` are set to `true`.

I've tried using `import ... from`, `import(...).then()`, `import ... = require(...)`, and renaming my `index.js` and the package's `index.js` to `index.cjs`.  They all result in the same error when I run in node:

> ```
> Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: E:\src\...\node_modules\stringify-object\index.js
> require() of ES modules is not supported.
> require() of E:\src\...\node_modules\stringify-object\index.js from E:\src\...\index.js is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
> Instead rename E:\src\...\node_modules\stringify-object\index.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module" from E:\src\...\node_modules\stringify-object\package.json.
> ```

I tried removing `"type": "module"` from the packages's `package.json`, but it relies on other packages with `"type": "module"`.

The last time I tried to figure this out, I gave up and went with a different package.  This really doesn't seem like it should be hard to do.

Comment: *"This really doesn't seem like it should be hard to do."* Yeah, we're in the uncomfortable place right now of moving from the old way to the new way. Eventually it'll be simple again, but... There were good reasons the new way had to be different, but it's still painful. Doubly or even triply-so for package authors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what I'd consider a workaround.  If I set `"module": "ESNext"` in `tsconfig.json` and rename the output to `index.mjs`, it works.  It's not particularly elegant, though.  There just *must* be a better way.

I'd be happy to accept a different, better answer.

---

As pointed out in the comment, setting `"type": "module"` in my project's `package.json` makes it so I do not need to rename `index.js` to `index.mjs`.

Comment: If you put `"type": "module"` in your `package.json`, you don't have to use that `.mjs` extension. What you're doing above is telling TypeScript to use ESM (native JavaScript modules) rather than CommonJS. So if you tell Node.js that's what you're doing via `package.json`, you don't need to use the filename to tell it that.

Comment: Ahh, I did try that before setting module: esnext, so maybe that'll do it.

Comment: this didn't work for me.. any suggestion

Comment: @Ahsan you set `"type": "module"` in package.json and `"module": "ESNext"` in tsconfig.json?

Comment: @dx_over_dt... yes tried that as well

Comment: @Ahsan are you using a bundler like webpack or rollup?